# Empty do block yesod after creating new handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I try to create a new route in yesod / haskell with a handler called state, but I get the error `empty 'do' block`

The steps to reproduce are the following:

1. Create new yesod application: `stack new haskellYesod yesodweb/simple`
2. `yesod add-handler` for adding a new handler with the params:

   - Name of route: State
   - Route Pattern: /state/
   - Methods: GET
3. Add following code in `src/Handler/State.hs`

```hs
module Handler.State where

import Import

getStateR :: Handler Html
getStateR = do
    defaultLayout $ do
        $(widgetFile "bla")
```

4. Create simple HTML site `templates/bla.hamlet`:

```html
<h1> BLA!
```

5. Start server with `stack exec yesod devel`

After that I get the error:

```
src/Handler/State.hs:7:21: error: Empty 'do' block
  |
7 |     defaultLayout $ do
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was missing extensions.  After adding the following, the error disappeared:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add this information. It does not belong in an answer.

Comment: Yep I did. But why? Because this answer is the solution to the question right?

Comment: @Sandro_V If you are saying that adding these extensions solved your question: then yes, this should be in an answer. On the other hand, if you are saying that you forgot to specify these extensions in your question, but adding them still does not solve your question: then no, this should not be an answer.

Comment: This was intended as an answer, not an addition to the question, so I've reverted the change to the question and updated this answer to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

What's happening is that without the `TemplateHaskell` extension, the syntax `$(...)` isn't recognized as intended.  Instead, it's parsed as a do-block followed by the operator `$` and then the expression `(...)`, as if you'd written:

```
getStateR = do
    defaultLayout $ (do $ widgetFile "bla")
                     ^^ empty do-block
```

You'd see the same problem with the standalone program:

```
main = do
    $(thiswontwork)
```

which is parsed as `main = do $ thiswontwork` and generates an `Empty 'do' block` message, too.

Adding `{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}` to the top of the `State.hs` file is enough to fix the problem.